# Captilizing a name in a ReSharper template

Tags: resharper

Is there a way to create a template in ReSharper that capitalizes a name?

For example I'd like to do something like this:

```
private $type$ _$name$;
public $type$ $uppercase_name$
{
    get { return _$name$; }
    set { _$name$ = value; }
}
```

So when I enter "*city*" for `$name$`, `$uppercase_name$` should automatically be "*City*".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok I did it:

1. When adding a template, on the right there's a part where you can choose a macro. Click on "*Choose Macro*" for `uppercase_name`.
2. Go to the end of the list. There's a macro called "*Value of **another variable** with the first character in upper case*". Choose that.
3. The part "*another variable*" will be in red in the macro selection part. Click on that.
4. Choose `name`.

Enjoy!

P.S. I have ReSharper 7.1. This may not be applicable for earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you! That has irritated me for too long. Glad I found this answer and can't believe I missed that macro right there in front of me.