# How to uppercase entire variable in Resharper Template?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper-7.1

I have a situation where I want the variable to be capitalized for documentation eg
(trivalized for example)

```
///AT+$COMMAND$

void At$COMMAND$()
{
}
```

So I want the user of the template to type in something like "Blah"  and that gets used in the method name, but the documentation part gets changed to "BLAH".

eg

```
///AT+BLAH
void AtBlah()
{
}
```

Can I do this?  I see in the macros I can capitalize the first letter, but I'd like the whole word capitalized.  Is it possible to create custom macros?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342501/captilizing-a-name-in-a-resharper-template

Answer (score 0):

They just updated documentation to meet changes in macros in Resharper 8. You can check it at http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/4.04+Live+Template+Macros+%28R8%29

With the new docs it is quite easy, my implementation goes here:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using JetBrains.DocumentModel;
using JetBrains.ReSharper.Feature.Services.LiveTemplates.Macros;
using JetBrains.ReSharper.Feature.Services.LiveTemplates.Hotspots;

namespace ReSharperPlugin
{
    [MacroDefinition("LiveTemplatesMacro.CapitalizeVariable", // macro name should be unique among all other macros, it's recommended to prefix it with your plugin name to achieve that
    ShortDescription = "Capitalizes variable {0:list}", // description of the macro to be shown in the list of macros
    LongDescription = "Capitalize full name of variable" // long description of the macro to be shown in the area below the list
    )]
    public class CapitalizeVariableMacro : IMacroDefinition
    {
        public string GetPlaceholder(IDocument document, IEnumerable<IMacroParameterValue> parameters)
        {
            return "A";
        }

        public ParameterInfo[] Parameters
        {
            get { return new[] {new ParameterInfo(ParameterType.VariableReference)}; }
        }
    }

    [MacroImplementation(Definition = typeof(CapitalizeVariableMacro))]
    public class CapitalizeVariableMacroImpl : SimpleMacroImplementation
    {
        private readonly IMacroParameterValueNew _parameter;

        public CapitalizeVariableMacroImpl([Optional] MacroParameterValueCollection parameters)
        {
            _parameter = parameters.OptionalFirstOrDefault();
        }

        public override string EvaluateQuickResult(IHotspotContext context)
        {
            return _parameter == null ? null : _parameter.GetValue().ToUpperInvariant();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is from a long past answer., so, I do not know if you are still monitoring it.  Could you provide a few steps as to how to implement this in current Visual Studio systems? Also, the link you had provided seems to have been taken offline.

Comment: Recent official discussion forums seem to suggest something like this should not be possible in latest Resharper editions. See https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/7841188294930-How-to-create-custom-template-parameter-macro-